# SQL Server Retrieve data out, the data got extra many space

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Server database. However, when I retrieve data from SQL Server, the data got a lot of extra spaces. I don't know how, did the client enter any space in my data? Is there anyway for me to not select those extra spaces from my database?

[image]

Comment: Whats the email column definition in the database?

Comment: @DaleBurrell nchar50,full text spec 'no', identity ' no, collation database default > SQL latin 1 general CP1 CI AS

Comment: There is your answer... nchar50 is always 50 chars no matter how long the data is. You need nvarchar(50) if you don't want blank spaces.

Comment: `nchar50` means it will always be padded out to fill up the 50.  in your C# simply do a `Trim()` to get rid of the spaces.

Comment: @DaleBurrell i tried , i even tried to reinsert data, it is same, not work

Comment: @ryan1555 you have to change the table definition so that the email column is nvarchar(50), and then you can update the table removing all the whitespace. Its probably easier to do what some of the others have suggested and trim in your app, because there is still nothing preventing an insert with additional whitespace.

Comment: @DaleBurrell solved, please mark your answer as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your column type is `nchar(50)`, it will always contain 50 chars no matter the length of data inserted. The remaining chars are padded with whitespace.

To fix this you have to change the table definition so that the email column is `nvarchar(50)`, and then you can update the table removing all the whitespace.

It's probably also worth doing what some of the other answers have suggested and trim additional whitespace in your app, because there is still nothing preventing an insert with additional whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Trim() function of C# to remove white spaces in your String or the value of your String variable. Kindly refer to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-trim-method/).

Comment: this is not the solution , the problem is if today client got enter space in my data, so should i trim those space data? it is no!

Comment: the trim will only remove the spaces at the front/rear of the text.  however if this is not agreeable and you for some reason want to preserve those spaces then you have to change your schema to use nvarchar(50)

Comment: @ryan1555, then you should add a front-end and back-end validation to your system so client cannot enter any space to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use trim() method as below while you retrieve your data and store in data variable as below.

```
    var data=record.ToList()[0].email.trim();
```

Or if you do not want to do that , you can use trim() method before storing the data in database. That way you will be 100% sure that your DB will not have blank spaces in that column.

I think you should do both , there is no harm in doing that.